# capybara rspec more indepth logging?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm retrieving a singleton can't be dumped error at some point after click_button is executed. All the rspec output tells me is:

```
1) home not logged in sign in should contain content with 'Add new charity
 Failure/Error: click_button "Install"
 TypeError:
   singleton can't be dumped
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/integration/home_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried using the -b option, but I don't get any new info. Using logging in my controller, I can see that the action goes through and finalizes with a redirect. It must fail at some point after that, before the receiving action is called. So if there's a way I can better see the stack trace, i might be able to pinpoint the issue.

**Added home_spec.rb**

Using the shopify_api gem as you can see.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "home" do

  before do
    @domain = "myshop.myshopify.com"
    @token = SecureRandom.hex(16)
    @shopify_session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(@domain, @token)
  end

  context "not logged in" do
    it "should be at login" do
      visit "/"
      page.should have_content("Install this app in a shop to get access to its private admin data")
    end

    describe "sign in" do
      before do
        ShopifyAPI::Session.should_receive(:new).and_return(@shopify_session)

        @shopify_session.should_receive(:valid?).and_return(true)

        ShopifyAPI::Session.any_instance.should_receive(:create_permission_url).and_return("/login/finalize?shop=#{@domain}&t=#{@token}")
      end

      it "should contain content with 'Add new charity" do
        visit "/"
        fill_in "shop", with: @domain
        click_button "Install"
        page.should have_content("Add new charity")
      end
    end
  end

  context "logged in" do
    before do
      page.set_rack_session(:shopify => @shopify_session)
    end

    it "should contain content with 'Add new charity" do
      visit "/"
      page.should have_content("Add new charity")
    end
  end

end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails' 
require 'capybara/dsl'
require "rack_session_access/capybara"

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

Rails.application.config do
  config.middleware.use RackSessionAccess::Middleware
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/factories"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # RSpec automatically cleans stuff out of backtraces;
  # sometimes this is annoying when trying to debug something e.g. a gem
  config.backtrace_clean_patterns = [
    /\/lib\d*\/ruby\//,
    /bin\//,
    /gems/,
    /spec\/spec_helper\.rb/,
    /lib\/rspec\/(core|expectations|matchers|mocks)/
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using something like Pry to make this easier?  It has something to do with one of your files that are being included in your home_spec.

Here is where you can find Pry: https://github.com/pry/pry

Then in your code you can insert `binding.pry` and you should be able to drop into the execution environment and inspect what's going on in an irb-like session.

Otherwise, you need to post your home_spec.rb so we can start to theorize.

Comment: I do have pry installed. I try it out and see if that gives me some more indepth knowledge with what's going on. I added the code for the spec file and the spec helper just in case. Thanks.